# Migrate from Zentyal to Samba4AD

Tags: active-directory, samba4, zentyal

I'm really new in Active Directory world and I plan to migrate from Zentyal 7 (a stack of multiple tools packaged in an Ubuntu OS) to a pure Samba4 Active Directory, and keep the same domain name.

I only have :

- users
- groups
- two GPO

I use Windows RSAT to manage groups, users, GPO.

I don't really know how to migrate. Zentyal uses Samba for the AD feature, so I've read [this doc](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Back_up_and_Restoring_a_Samba_AD_DC#Offline.2Flocal_DC_backup). It seems easy to backup and restore :

1. Backup on Zentyal with `sudo samba-tool domain backup offline --targetdir=<output-dir>`
2. Stop the current Domain Controller
3. Setup a new machine with a fresh Samba4, same hostname and IP
4. Restore on new server with `sudo samba-tool domain backup restore --backup-file=<tar-file> --newservername=<DC-name> --targetdir=<new-samba-dir>`
5. Start the new Samba server with `samba -s <targetdir>/etc/smb.conf`

Do you see anything that could go wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: but while you already using samba, why do you want to do the same one times more?

Comment: Because Zentyal is a little bit tricky to update (some updates have break the entire OS, GUI...), there are too many useless packages installed (for my goal), it takes more resources (it's a GUI OS)... And I'm interested to deploy an AD with a pure Samba4, to really understand the configuration from scratch, not just the click-button way.

Comment: I think you could find your luck [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/74370/how-to-migrate-samba-user-accounts-to-a-new-linux-server) since it's basically the same software, however you did not show the configuration so noone can tell you a bit exactly about the configuration what is to do